# Three.js manipulate 3D mouse coordinates by new direction

Tags: javascript, three.js, mousemove

i have a problem at setting a new mouse position. I have an Object which is moving and rotating free in a Space and following the position of the pointerlocked cursor. Targetposition is a Vector3 positioned behind the object. Now i want to make an Animation which moves the object in the opposite direction by rotating it smoothly. So I disable my mouseListener and rotate the object with the given Three.js functions. But after I enable my listener the targetPosition turns back to the mouse position and makes the move useless. So now i want to calculate the mouse Position for my new Targetposition after the animation. How can i do that ?

The function for the 3D mouse coordinates looks something like this:

```
enter code here
   mouseY = Math.max(-85, Math.min(70, -mouseY));
   phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 + mouseY);
   theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(mouseX);

   targetPosition.x = object.position.x + 100 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
   targetPosition.y = object.position.y + 100 * Math.cos(phi);
   targetPosition.z = object.position.z + 100 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
   object.lookAt(targetPosition);
```

Comment: Seems like you could just "solve" for the mouse positions, granted that would take some decent math there

Comment: if you know how .. speak please :)